# How to route base path to ASP.NET Core API service in Docker container on Linux host

Tags: asp.net, linux, docker

We have a .NET Core 3.1 API service deployed on a Windows 2019 server named devweb. The service runs in IIS in a virtual directory /OnPrem.

We also have a reverse proxy that authenticates requests such as `ourproxy/MyApp/OnPrem/api/mydata/1` and forwards the request to `devweb/OnPrem/api/mydata/1`.

I want to move this on-premise API service to a Docker container, so we can host it on a Linux box. I have packaged the API service as a platform-neutral .NET Core Docker container that exposes ports 80 and 443. Calls to the service in the Docker container are working correctly. For example, the URL `MyDevPC/api/mydata/1` is returning the correct data.

My problem: our proxy implementation sends the `/OnPrem` base URL to the host. I can setup the container as-is to handle `host/api/mydata/1`, but I need the host to be able to handle the URL `host/OnPrem/api/mydata/1` and route this request to the Docker container. In Windows IIS, this could be done by configuring an Application in a virtual directory with a path of `/OnPrem`. I am new to Docker containers and Linux, so I am not sure what my options are in a Linux host with a service in a Docker container.

**How would I accomplish creating the equivalent of an IIS virtual directory in a Linux host with a Docker container?**

This is currently the only container on the host machine, but I anticipate a future in which we may have multiple containers running multiple web apps on a given host.

Comment: For your Docker container, is it going to be on Windows container (and thus use IIS internally) or will it be a Linux container (and therefore be expected to be fronted with something like Nginx)?

Comment: @mason The Docker container will be hosted on a Linux server. Not sure which distro our DevOps team used for it, but I can find out if necessary. The container itself is currently based on aspnet:3.1-buster-slim which is .NET Core 3.1 on a Linux Debian distribution.

Comment: Also note that my experience with Linux is minimal. I am a Windows dinosaur. (Thank goodness for the Internet!)

Comment: Microsoft best practice is to put something in front of your Linux hosted ASP.NET Core apps such as Nginx or Apache. You can probably do what you're wanting to accomplish with Nginx or Apache (you might also check other tools like [Traefik](https://traefik.io/traefik/) or [Envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/)). The specific implementation will be specific to the tool you're using to front your app I think. Of course, I don't have a ton of experience hosting ASP.NET Core in Docker, so I could be completely wrong.